# Mac Mini 1,1 (10.6.8) Missing libc++

Tags: mac, snow-leopard, mac-mini, homebrew

My Mac Mini 1,1 running Snow Leopard 10.6.8 is missing libc++. Is there a version for OS X 10.6.8? Is there a way to install it again through Homebrew?

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out I had a purchased copy of Xcode for Snow Leopard. Installing that fixed it.